# get all issues stored in jira

Tags: java, jira, jql, jira-rest-java-api, jira-rest-api

hi i want to get all issues stored in jira from java using jql or any othere way.
i try to use this code:

```
for(String name:getProjectsNames()){
String jqlRequest = "project =  \""+name+"\"";

    SearchResult result = restClient.getSearchClient().searchJql(
            jqlRequest, 10000,0, pm);

    final Iterable<BasicIssue> issues = result.getIssues();
    for (BasicIssue is : issues) {
        Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue(is.getKey(), pm);
        ...........

    }
```

it give me the result but it take a very long time.
is there a query or a rest API URL or any other way that give me all issues?
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JIRA REST API will give you all the info from each issue at a rate of a few issues/second. The Inquisitor add-on at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.citrix.jira.inquisitor will give you thousands of issues per second but only the standard JIRA fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way. There is one table in JIRA database named "**dbo.jiraissue**". If you have access to that database then you can fetch all the ids of all issues. After fetching this data you can send this REST request "**localhost/rest/api/2/issue/issue_id" and get JSON response. Of course you have to write some code for this but this is one way I know to get all issues.